# Laravel Blade html image

Tags: laravel, image, laravel-blade

My image file path is `public/img/stuvi-logo.png` and
my app.blade.php file path is `resources/views/app.blade.php`

Inside of my app.blade.php file I use `{{HTML::image('/img/stuvi-logo.png')}}`
to display an image.
I don't understand why this won't find the image.
What is the root folder of the `image()` method?

Comment: `public/img/logo.png` can't be available at `/img/stuvi-logo.png`, I mean, even the file names are different. Is that a typo in the question or your program?

Comment: If you inspect your rendered code, what do you see? Is the url to it correct?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

If you use bootstrap, you might use this -

```
 <img src="{{URL::asset('/image/propic.png')}}" alt="profile Pic" height="200" width="200">
```

note: inside **public** folder create a new folder named **image** then put your images there. Using `URL::asset()` you can directly access to the **public** folder.

Answer (score 21):

**Change** `/img/stuvi-logo.png` **to** `img/stuvi-logo.png`

```
{{ HTML::image('img/stuvi-logo.png', 'alt text', array('class' => 'css-class')) }}
```

**Which produces the following HTML**.

```
<img src="http://your.url/img/stuvi-logo.png" class="css-class" alt="alt text">
```

**Update** After Laravel 5 this package has been deprecated and maintained as a separate external package. in order to work need to add this `composer require laravelcollective/html`. more details https://laravelcollective.com/

Comment: It's wrong way ,

{{ HTML::image('img/stuvi-logo.png', 'alt text', array('class' => 'css-class')) }}

i am getting this error

 " Class "HTML" not found "

Comment: The url specified is no longer relevant and does not link to/reference the package which has been abandoned.

Answer (score 15):

as of now, you can use

```
<img src="{{ asset('images/foo.png') }}" alt="tag">
```

Comment: Also works with `background-image` property

Comment: yes of course, it will work just as expected since it is processed by php.

Comment: works on laravel 8

Answer (score 5):

In Laravel 5.x you can use [laravelcollective/html](http://laravelcollective.com/docs/5.1/html) and the syntax:

```
{!! Html::image('img/logo.png') !!}
```

Comment: Irrelevant!! The Html package has been removed from Laravel 5. You can still use it but you will need to explicitly include the package inside the framework. Worth saying it I think...

Comment: I corrected the answer to specify the laravelcollective/html package

Comment: After installing the Forms & HTML collective package (5.3), both syntax from the accepted answer and this one will work. This answer does not take capital `HTML` .. I stumbled on that ..

Answer (score 3):

It will look for an image inside of a *public/storage* folder where you can define your own *image* folder

```
<img src="{{ Storage::url($post->image->path) }}" alt="">
```

Always try to *dump* what you are looking for first and than pass it to a url method.

Also, you can create your own url() method inside your Image model if you have some

```
public function url()
{
    return Storage::url($this->path);
}
```

Then in your blade template you can use this method as follows:

```
<img src="{{ $post->image->url() }}" alt="">
```

Answer (score 2):

you can Using asset() you can directly access to the image folder.

```
<img src="{{asset('img/stuvi-logo.png')}}" alt="logo" class="img-size-50 mr-3 img-circle">
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with laravel **5.3..**.
This is how I did it and very easy.
for example logo in the blade page view

```
****<image img src="/img/logo.png" alt="Logo"></image>****
```

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel 5.x, you can also do like this .

`<img class="img-responsive" src="{{URL::to('/')}}/img/stuvi-logo.png" alt=""/>`

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please [include an explanation for your code](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/269535), as that really helps to improve the quality of your post.  Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

in my case this worked perfectly

```
<img  style="border-radius: 50%;height: 50px;width: 80px;"  src="<?php echo asset("storage/TeacherImages/{$studydata->teacher->profilePic}")?>">
```

this code is used to display image from folder

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the file you want to display is public try adding the variable in your Mail builder function.

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    $img_url = env('APP_URL')."/img/stuvi-logo.png";

    return (new MailMessage)
                ->subject('Test')
                ->markdown('vendor.mail.markdown.message', [
                                                    'data' => $this->data,
                                                    'img_url'=>$img_url
        ]);
}
```

And then use your 'img_url' variable set in the array in your email blade file.

```
< img src={{img_url}} alt="Logo" height="50"/>
```

> This worked for me on Laravel 8.xx.