# show img with url in laravel 5.4

Tags: image, laravel

I have a image that want show in slide show I use html tag `<img src="">`,
I'm new in laravel and I don't Know How to show image in my blade.
How I can use `<img>` tag in laravel?

Comment: Exactly the same way?

Comment: Nothing new, You can use custom css or bootstrap to style it as well

Comment: how do you store image name or path?

Comment: @Mohammadb I don't know How I can store images in public directory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel Blade html image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858097/laravel-blade-html-image)

Comment: Please do some research before you ask this type of silly questions, you can get result without asking this type of question here.

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik  thanks! But I use laravel5.4 and it is different with other questions

Comment: There is no difference, it can work in any version, you've to install package called "laravelcollective"

Comment: @PandhiBhaumik Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have stored images inside laravel public directory then, you can use `asset` which refers to `public/` directory.

If you have image at `public/images/abc.png` then, you can add image in view like this:

```
 <img src="{{ asset('images/abc.png') }}">
```

Comment: please tell me How I can stored image in public directory?

Comment: Currenly where are you storing images ?

Comment: Until Now I don't use laravel just use css and html with `<img>` tag

Comment: Then, just use like elsewhere

Answer (score 2):

```
<img src="{{ asset('/public/upload/image.jpg') }}">
```

If your image in public folder