# Why is the avatar on app.blade is broken whenever I open links that has id?

Tags: laravel

Whenever I open an item the link would be

> http://localhost/mywebsite/public/item/{$item_id}

the avatar will break. Below is the code I used

```
<img src="uploads/avatars/{{ Auth::user()->avatar }}">
```

The location of the image is `C:\xampp\htdocs\mywebsite\public\uploads\avatars`

Comment: what's your laravel version?

Comment: slap a '/' before 'uploads/avatars'
<img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ Auth::user()->avatar }}">

Comment: @okante it's 5.4

Comment: do you have a helper named `public_path()` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Absolute vs relative URLs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls)

Comment: It's not helping @ceejayoz

Comment: This is the answer I've been looking for
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858097/laravel-blade-html-image

Answer (score 1):

I presume that as you are using relative URLs the translated path in browser will be `http://localhost/mywebsite/public/item/{$item_id}/uploads/avatars/{{ Auth::user()->avatar }}`

And that's not what you want

Try

```
<img src="http://localhost/mywebsite/public/uploads/avatars/{{ Auth::user()->avatar }}">
```

In production in will be just

```
<img src="/uploads/avatars/{{ Auth::user()->avatar }}">
```

Am not sure it will work on xampp though

So to say, I recommend using Laravel Valet or Homestead instead of Xampp, it cuts some problems like yours off.

Comment: What is it that I want?

Comment: @JohnDoe You'll want to use `public_path()` to construct the correct URL, maybe combined with the `asset()` helper. Both are in the docs.

Comment: you just added a `/`. I also tried that one, didn't work. Thank you for your reply

Comment: Adding a `/` won't work, because your URLs have `/mywebsite/public/` at the start. Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005079/absolute-vs-relative-urls - `src="uploads` is relative to the current URL, including any folders.

Answer (score -2):

in File model i created a function to get file encoded base64

```
public function getFile()
{
    $path = storage_path('app'). "/" . $this->path;
    $type = File::mimeType($path);

    $file = Storage::disk('local')->get("/". $this->path);

    return "data:image/png;base64,".base64_encode($file);
}
```

in blade You can use like that

```
 <img src = '$file->getFile()'>
```

Comment: Whaaaaat? This is a horrible idea. Can't be cached by the browser, takes up 1/3 more bytes...

Comment: hahaha I know but i am using this sometimes to display small images