# How to display image from another disk in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, image, samba, file-storage

I am trying to display an image in my Laravel application. The image comes from another disk which is a samba share. I followed the configuration instructions from the Laravel Doc, here is my setup:

**filesystems.php**

```
'shop_storage' => [
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => env('SHOP_STORAGE_PATH', base_path('shop_storage')),
    'dir' => [
        'public' => 0777,
        'private' => 0777,
    ]
],
```

My samba share is mounted into the root folder /shop_storage inside my Laravel application with the following command:
`sudo mount.cifs //PATH_TO_FILE_SHARE/ARMMAG ./shop_storage -o credentials=$HOME/.smbcredentials,rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,mfsymlinks`

I correctly see all files when I open the folder.
Then, I added a Symlink from `/public/storage` to `/shop_storage` with the following command:
`sudo ln -s /shop_storage /public/storage` (Using full path starting at /home, removed here for privacy)
When I open `/public/storage`, I correctly see the symlink pointing to the samba share. If I click to open it, I see all the files. The file I am looking for exists.

[image: directory structure]

The problem is when I am trying to display it in my webpage, the request return a 404.
Here is some of the things that I have tried:

```
<img src="{{\Storage::disk('shop_storage')->url('products/16/MAZJKj59EY0XQ57oKIibKr33eZ5dsqAPx44MCHHJ.png')}}">
<img src="http://localhost:8000/shop_storage/products/16/MAZJKj59EY0XQ57oKIibKr33eZ5dsqAPx44MCHHJ.png">
<img src="{{asset('products/16/MAZJKj59EY0XQ57oKIibKr33eZ5dsqAPx44MCHHJ.png')}}">
<img src="{{asset('storage/products/16/MAZJKj59EY0XQ57oKIibKr33eZ5dsqAPx44MCHHJ.png')}}">
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit**
After some try/error, I managed to get a different response with the following syntax:
 `<img src="{{asset('storage/shop_storage/products/16/MAZJKj59EY0XQ57oKIibKr33eZ5dsqAPx44MCHHJ.png')}}">`
Now, I am getting the foloowing error

```
You don't have permission to access /storage/shop_storage/products/16/MAZJKj59EY0XQ57oKIibKr33eZ5dsqAPx44MCHHJ.png on this server.
```

My permission are set to 777, what could cause this?

Comment: https://laravel-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/filesystem/#obtaining-disk-instances

```Remember, if you are using the local driver, all files that should be publicly accessible should be placed in the storage/app/public directory. Furthermore, you should create a symbolic link at public/storage which points to the storage/app/public directory.```

Comment: ```{{ HTML::image('img/stuvi-logo.png', 'alt text', array('class' => 'css-class')) }}```  seen here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29858097/laravel-blade-html-image

Comment: I don't think this is the solution to my problem. I don't want to store my files under storage/app/public, as stated, I want them to be on my samba share. That's why I created a symlink that points there instead of storage/app/public

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30191330/laravel-5-how-to-access-image-uploaded-in-storage-within-view

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What I ended up doing to make this work is mount my share directly into public/storage instead of using symlinks. Then any I could access the file using the laravel asset helper:

`<img src="{{asset('storage/products/16/MAZJKj59EY0XQ57oKIibKr33eZ5dsqAPx44MCHHJ.png')}}">`